Integral of a function w.r.t. Lebesgue measure
In a certain exercise I have been asked to prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dm = \infty$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. It is the first time that I study measure theory, so I'm really lost. I would really appreciate any hint.

What are you being asked? To prove ... what? That the integral converges/diverges?

Sorry, I'll edit it

You can probably find some sequence of simple functions, that converges to $\frac{1}{x}$ from below, which  evaluates to a divergent sequence.

So basically, the calculus of Lebesgue integrals can be usually reduced to study sequences of simple functions?

Every Lebesgue integral is a supremum of integrals of simple functions bounded from above by the function you are integrating. But that is just the definition. On Riemann-integrable functions both Lebesgue and Riemann integrals agree with each other, so there you only need the regular integration rules you already know.
